# MongoDB - Is there any advantage in moving frequently updated fields to different collections?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to **MongoDB** and **Document-Oriented Databases** and while I was migrating a relational database to this whole new concept of storing a question raised:

- In relational databases it's usually a good idea to create a new table to store frequently updated fields (let's say you have a `user's table` and a `last_activity` one) so that the slow write operations don't lock the other tables.

Is there any advantage of doing the same in **MongoDB**, since the read operations seem to be very performant and doing two queries wouldn't be much of a problem?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version mongodb 3.2, is already in use by default [wiredtiger](http://www.wiredtiger.com/). This engine is not necessary to create additional collections.
Well, do not forget to create updatable fields Index.

```
db.test.ensureIndex({name: 1});
db.test.update({"name":"Alex"}, {$set:{"last_name":"alexeev"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default storage engine, MMAPv1, then you have collection-level concurrency and it may be beneficial to create new collections for frequently updated fields.

However, the WiredTiger storage engine has document-level concurrency and there is no need to create additional tables. 
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/wiredtiger/